# Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling

The PHP manual for [`mysqli_connect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) suggests checking for the return value and displaying the error messages on the screen.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

Similarly for OOP-style constructor this is suggested:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Some users on Stack Overflow even used code with `mysqli_error($conn)` such as this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'a', 'a');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

However, in the past few weeks I have been asking myself a question, why would I need to do that? The output of the first example is:

> Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   C:\xampp\...\mysqli.php on line 4
>
> Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 1045 Debugging
>   error: Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password:
>   YES)

As you can see the error message is displayed twice! The manual "debugging" actually provides less information.

Should we ever manually check for connection errors? Would we ever get more information this way than from the automatic warning? Is this the recommended practice?

Comment: FWIW I really did search for this information on the Internet and could not find anything reliable. If anyone has anything to add or contradict in my answer, I would happily take constructive criticism.

Comment: Your question is about checking for connection errors. Your answer is about displaying them. As you rightly mention in your answer, PHP code will not stop in the event of a warning, so if you want to halt code execution at the point of a connection error, you have to check for them.

Comment: @miken32 I am not sure I understand. If an exception happens the code stops execution right away, correct? If you don't enable exceptions, it means that you do not want the code to stop in case of error. Either way, there is no need to check for errors, PHP can do it for you.

Comment: True, I was assuming default settings where mysqli does not throw exceptions.

Comment: @miken32 Surely then it is better to enable the error reporting, rather than checking manually with an if statement after every function call, correct?

Comment: By "enable the error reporting" you mean configure mysqli to throw exceptions? Absolutely; I never use mysqli personally, but I'll keep it in mind when answering mysqli questions.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Never display connection errors manually!

MySQLi will generate a warning if it is unable to open the connection to MySQL. This warning tells you all you need to know including the error code, error message, and the place in the code where it happened. Checking for the error manually will not give you any more information.

If you can't see the warning and your connection cannot be created, it might mean that your PHP is not configured to show them. In that case, you must check the error log file on your server. If you do not know where that is, use [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to get that information and search for `error_log`. It will tell you where the error log file is located.

If there is no warning in the error logs, it could mean that your PHP has error reporting silenced (either completely or just warnings). Check your PHP configuration.
In the **production** environment these settings should be maintained:

- `error_reporting` must be `E_ALL`
- `log_errors` must be `On`
- `display_errors` must be **`Off`**

In the **development** environment these settings should be maintained:

- `error_reporting` must be `E_ALL`
- `log_errors` must be `On`
- `display_errors` must be **`On`**

As you can see in the error message your database username and password have been revealed to the end user. This is sensitive information that you do not want to show anyone. In fact, a normal user would not understand this cryptic message. This is why `display_errors` must always be switched off in the production environment. Logging the errors on the server is safe.

#### Warnings vs. Exceptions

Warnings do not stop the script. If a warning is emitted the script will keep on executing until it encounters a fatal error. In most cases, you would want to throw an exception to stop the script. **Do not use `die/exit`!** If mysqli connection cannot be made, an exception should be thrown and if it is unhandled it will bubble up and stop the script with a fatal error. You can configure mysqli to throw exceptions automatically. This is invaluable because all mysqli functions can fail for many reasons and they will not inform you about any problems unless you check for errors manually every single one of them. Use the following line before opening the connection:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Do not catch the exceptions unless you really know what to do with them! One possible use case is described in [How to connect properly using mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect#error_handling)

#### Can `mysqli_error()` show any connection-related problems?

No. `mysqli_error($conn)` expects that the mysqli connection was successful. `$conn` must be a valid mysqli connection otherwise you would get this error message:

> Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\...

Neither `$conn->error` nor `mysqli_error($conn)` can display any connection-related errors!

*Related:* [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)